# Whats the code to create a directory if it doesnt exist?

Tags: c#, create-directory

I am having a problem with coding my save-directory. I want it to create a folder called "Ausgabe" (Output) on the current users Desktop, but I do not know how to check if it already exists and if it doesn't then create it.

This is my current code for that part so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    // need some code here
}
```

What do I add in order to make it do what I want it to do?

Comment: it is not appropriate to add new questions to a question. This will create an endless loop making some of the proper answers received incomplete and forcing people to keep up with your requirements. Future readers searching for an answer to your second question will not be helped in this way. You can easily post a new question where many more people can answer a precise and focused question

Comment: Oh alright thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a directory exists using

```
Directory.Exists(pathToDirectory)
```

and create a directory using

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToDirectory)
```

EDIT In response to your comment:

```
string directoryPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Ausgabe")
```

should give you the path to a folder named 'Ausgabe' in the users Desktop-folder.

Comment: Ok thank you. About the pathToDirectory: string of path is the path of the current users desktop. How do I add the folder to it that I want to check for existence (in this case folder Ausgabe)?

Comment: @tegabyte Added response to post

Comment: Do note you do not need to call `Directory.Exists` before `Directory.CreateDirectory`, since `Directory.CreateDirectory` and `DirectoryInfo.Create` do nothing if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx). If the directory exists the method will not create it (in other words it contains a call to Directory.Exists internally)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    public Form1()
    {
         string myFolder = Path.Combine(path, "Ausgabe");
         Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder);
    }
```

To use this method you need to add a *using System.IO* to the top of your Form1.cs file.

I wish also to say that the Desktop is not the most appropriate place to create a directory for your application. There is a proper place provided by the System and it is under the ProgramData enum (CommonApplicationData or ApplicationData)

```
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Comment: To answer the big question about why I do not use ApplicationData: I want the Users to have direct access to those files as they document something they might want to upload to a database.

Comment: Well that's a valid enough reason to have it in the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

> As per this [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx), the `Directory.CreateDirectory Method (String)` will
>   Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path
>   unless they already exist.

So it is fine to use like this:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string desktopFolder = Path.Combine(path, "New Folder");
Directory.CreateDirectory(desktopFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Directory.Exists() method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Your code would propebly look something like this:

```
public static void Main() 
    {
        // Specify the directory you want to manipulate.
        string path = @"c:\MyDir";

        try 
        {
            // Determine whether the directory exists.
            if (Directory.Exists(path)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                return;
            }

            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));

            // Delete the directory.
            di.Delete();
            Console.WriteLine("The directory was deleted successfully.");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        } 
        finally {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a recent issue so here is my solution,

I had to find the deployed directory

```
var deployedDir = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase;          
            deployedDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(deployedDir);
            deployedDir = deployedDir.Replace("file:\\", "");
            var pathToDirectory= Path.Combine(deployedDir, "YourFileName");
```

Then do what the above answers show and create the directory if it doesnt exist,

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToDirectory)
```